# How does typescript fit this method

Tags: typescript

`test.js`

```js
const testList = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 4, 1, 1];
const lastIndex = testList.findLastIndex((e:number) => e === 100);
// Property 'findLastIndex' does not exist on type 'number[]'. Did you mean 'findIndex'?ts(2551)
// lib.es2015.core.d.ts(43, 5): 'findIndex' is declared here.
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
...
"target": "ES6",           
...
```

Does the findLastIndex method need any settings of ts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`findLast()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast) and [the `findLastIndex()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex) are currently, as of 2023-01-15, part of a [proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-array-find-from-last/) which has reached Stage 4 of [the TC39 process](https://tc39.es/process-document/).  Thus they are not currently in any released version of ECMAScript, but they *are* in [the ESNext version](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) and will therefore appear in ES2023.

For TypeScript, [microsoft/TypeScript#48829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48829) was filed to support these additions.  They were implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#49636](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49636) which was just [merged into the TS main branch on 2023-01-13](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49636#event-8225209673) (two days ago).  So no currently released version of TypeScript supports them, but they *are* in the [`typescript@next` nightly version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/next) and will be released with TypeScript 5.0.

So, for now, if you want to access these methods without adding your own declarations for them, you should use the nightly version of TypeScript with your `--target` set to `"ESNext"` (or maybe `"ES2023"` if the option is available).

[Playground link to code, TS5.0-dev with ESNext target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.0.0-dev.20230115#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0AyBLaMC8MDaBGANDAEyEkwAshArKYZcXdUzAGyEDsHhAHD3zAQqFBuALoBuALAAoUJFgAbAIbQAkmAAm8AB6Y4iKKmgA6AGYpNSFVHVbtACnvwAXGACuAWwBG8AE4BKTAA+GHhMDCxcAAYo-3EgA)

Answer (score 0):

```
let lastIndex = -1;
for (let i = testList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (testList[i] === 100) {
        lastIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(lastIndex); // -1 if 100 is not in the list, otherwise the last index of 100
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question as asked, which is specifically about [the new `findLastIndex()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a typescript problem, there are some discussions about it:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48829
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49453

I think this answer is what you're looking for:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48829#issuecomment-1295493436